# SQL syntax error when using count

Tags: sql, count, percentage

I am trying to calculate the percentage but the count query comes with an error, below is the query

```
SELECT     COUNT([advice] <>  '0') * 100  / COUNT( DISTINCT userID) As Perc
FROM         tbUser
GROUP BY userID
```

Its comes up with the error incorrect syntax near '<' , What i simply want to do is count the advice column with rows having '0' value then divide it by total users to get the percentage.

Any suggestion where i am getting it wrong
Thanks

Comment: `COUNT` counts the records for which field has a value (non-null), and doesn't accept additional conditions. That's why your solution is what Andomar posted, using sum.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
COUNT([advice] <>  '0')
```

With:

```
sum(case when advice <> '0' then 1 end)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `else 0`? Otherwise you will get NULL as soon as there is at least one `advice = '0'`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: `sum` ignores `null`, f.e. `sum(0, 1, null)` returns 1

Comment: Indeed. I always thought it was different.